# Magento 1.9 rewrite/redirect issue

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, redirect-url

Magento is redirecting to the wrong url.
Checked htaccess as I thought there is a problem but not, there is no redirect for this url. So I've checked rewrite table but there is no obvious cause.
For example, I have two products, different url's different SKU's
and the category list seems is pointing to the correct url but once I click on link it redirecting me to the other product with different url and SKU.
How to find where is the rewrite/redirect? Every url check says everything is fine but it does not say anything how or where this redirect is created/executed.
I'm confised

Also checked rewrites, just in case deleted every url directly related to the product I'm interrested in from the list and now it seems to work. But still, there was no obvious reason why it does it.
 Any ideas ?

Comment: If you think that's something wrong with the magento routing you can debug this in the method `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match()`. There is where the magic of routing happens.